# Why wont it create a group?

Tags: groups, team-sites

I just started using Sharepoint Online and I am not seeing the default options that were rolled out in may 2016. 
When I try to create a new site I get this prompt:
[image]

What I am trying to get looks more like this:

[image]

What setting enables this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that functionality is not available in most (any?) tenants yet, dispite some MS communication stating otherwise.

Normally new functionality is rolled out in waves, with first-release tenants getting it first. But, I have several example of first-release tenants not having this functionality yet, but only really one tenant where it has been rolled out